# solr schema design, multiple key/vals

Tags: solr

I have a schema I'm trying to design in solr the data is simple with just a productKey, then I take that product key, hit a few different websites and store their product descriptions of that product for searching.

for example:
productKey: 1234, I hit siteA and got back "cool razor", siteB I back "neat razor"

so ideally in a document I'd like to store something that's similar in concept to:

(PSUDOCODE)

```
<doc>
<productKey>1234</productKey>
<site>siteA</site>
<desc>coolrazor</desc>
<site>siteB</site>
<desc>near razor</desc>
</doc>
```

but I'd like to be able to do searches like, show me all the docs where siteA thought something had "cool razor" in it only. right now it would pull any site that had razor in the desc.

any fix for that?

Comment: why dont you use redis for your task instead of solr...this problem is well suited for redis.

Comment: also please improve your sentence a bit starting from "site A though something had......" how is site A thinking?

Comment: this problem is not suited for redis, redis is a key lookup, not a search index.

Answer (score 0):

What type of Analyser are you using for desc field? I think, you will need to use solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory on the description field.

Refer to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters

Comment: I'm not using anything at the moment, trying to figure out how to get started on a correct schema

Answer (score 0):

I would create one document per site, having something else than productKey as the unique id field.

Comment: assume 100 million prouducts, and data from 50 different sites, so a doc per site would yield 500 million docs in that case.